# ，如禮何？，如樂何？= rituals according to what?

Tags: translation

子曰：「人而不仁，如禮何？人而不仁，如樂何？
Hello, this is Confucius:
I have translated it into: man without virtue, rituals (manners) according to what? man without virtue, music according to what?
this would mean: what's the value of rituals without virtue in heart? what's the value of music, without virtue?
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

about 論語﹒八佾　子曰﹒人而不仁﹒如禮何﹒人而不仁﹒如樂何

[james legge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Legge)'s translation:

```
(子曰) the master said 
(人而不仁) if a man be without the virtues proper to humanity
(如禮何) what has he to do with the rites of propriety
(人而不仁) if a man be without the virtues proper to humanity
(如樂何) what has he to do with music
```

traditionally, there're several ways to explain:

one is to expand the verses to "子曰﹒人而不仁﹒何以為禮樂"

```
(子曰) the master said
(人而不仁) if a man has no benevolence
(如禮何) how can he perform ritual
(人而不仁) if a man has no benevolence
(如樂何) how can he perform music
```

another is to treat it as "子曰﹒人而不仁﹒禮樂沒奈何"

```
(子曰) the master said
(人而不仁) if a man has no benevolence
(如禮何) what can ritual do
(人而不仁) if a man has no benevolence
(如樂何) what can music do
```

have fun :)

edited, add links.

the internet archive has some james legge's books, these two are english translation of the classic four:

[the four books](https://archive.org/details/fourbooksgreatle00confuoft)

[註釋校正華英四書](https://archive.org/details/zhushijiaozhengh00legg)